# How to Install boost via Homebrew?

Tags: boost, installation, homebrew

Installing boost failed.

```
==> Exit Status: 1http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/boost.rb#L69
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: 97fa532a10613cd314f08b15b06a20b866919689
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.6.8
Kernel Architecture: i386
Ruby: 1.8.7-174
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 4.0.2
GCC-4.0: build 5494
GCC-4.2: build 5666
LLVM: build 2335
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags

CC: /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
CXX: /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++ => /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
LD: /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
CFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -msse4.1 -w -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -msse4.1 -w -pipe
MAKEFLAGS: -j2

Error: Failed executing: ./bjam --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.47.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.47.0/lib -j2 --layout=tagged --user-config=user-config.jam threading=multi install
If `brew doctor' does not help diagnose the issue, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue
```

How can I install boost?

System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Kernel Vesion: Darwin 10.8.0

Comment: Have you triede `brew doctor`?

Comment: Result of brew doctor is below.
https://gist.github.com/1192578
I think this is not effect to install boost, isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sharpie fixed this!
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7633

It's my local python's problem. (I understand)

I use the `--without-python` option and I can install boost.

Comment: Yep, `brew install --without-python boost` worked for be on 10.7.2.