# library not found for lboost_python

Tags: python, boost

When installing boost i remember having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298289/how-to-install-boost-via-homebrew) problem which the fix was to use `--without-python` option.
When i now go `brew install boost`
it gives `Warning: boost-1.58.0 already installed` 
But now when trying to configure [graph_tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/) i get `library not found for -lboost_python` and indeed there is nothing in `ls /usr/local/lib/libboost_python*` [where my boost is installed](http://main-discussion-list-for-the-graph-tool-project.982480.n3.nabble.com/Problem-with-configure-and-Boost-Python-td4024944.html).
But there are plenty of other boost files:

ls libboost*

```
libboost_atomic-mt.a            libboost_filesystem.a           libboost_math_c99f-mt.a         libboost_program_options-mt.a       libboost_test_exec_monitor-mt.a
libboost_atomic-mt.dylib        libboost_filesystem.dylib       libboost_math_c99f-mt.dylib     libboost_program_options-mt.dylib   libboost_test_exec_monitor.a
libboost_chrono-mt.a            libboost_graph-mt.a         libboost_math_c99f.a            libboost_program_options.a      libboost_thread-mt.a
libboost_chrono-mt.dylib        libboost_graph-mt.dylib         libboost_math_c99f.dylib        libboost_program_options.dylib      libboost_thread-mt.dylib
libboost_chrono.a           libboost_graph.a            libboost_math_c99l-mt.a         libboost_random-mt.a            libboost_timer-mt.a
libboost_chrono.dylib           libboost_graph.dylib            libboost_math_c99l-mt.dylib     libboost_random-mt.dylib        libboost_timer-mt.dylib
libboost_container-mt.a         libboost_iostreams-mt.a         libboost_math_c99l.a            libboost_random.a           libboost_timer.a
libboost_container-mt.dylib     libboost_iostreams-mt.dylib     libboost_math_c99l.dylib        libboost_random.dylib           libboost_timer.dylib
libboost_container.a            libboost_iostreams.a            libboost_math_tr1-mt.a          libboost_regex-mt.a         libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.a
libboost_container.dylib        libboost_iostreams.dylib        libboost_math_tr1-mt.dylib      libboost_regex-mt.dylib         libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib
libboost_context-mt.a           libboost_locale-mt.a            libboost_math_tr1.a         libboost_regex.a            libboost_unit_test_framework.a
libboost_context-mt.dylib       libboost_locale-mt.dylib        libboost_math_tr1.dylib         libboost_regex.dylib            libboost_unit_test_framework.dylib
libboost_coroutine-mt.a         libboost_log-mt.a           libboost_math_tr1f-mt.a         libboost_serialization-mt.a     libboost_wave-mt.a
libboost_coroutine-mt.dylib     libboost_log-mt.dylib           libboost_math_tr1f-mt.dylib     libboost_serialization-mt.dylib     libboost_wave-mt.dylib
libboost_coroutine.a            libboost_log.a              libboost_math_tr1f.a            libboost_serialization.a        libboost_wave.a
libboost_coroutine.dylib        libboost_log.dylib          libboost_math_tr1f.dylib        libboost_serialization.dylib        libboost_wave.dylib
libboost_date_time-mt.a         libboost_log_setup-mt.a         libboost_math_tr1l-mt.a         libboost_signals-mt.a           libboost_wserialization-mt.a
libboost_date_time-mt.dylib     libboost_log_setup-mt.dylib     libboost_math_tr1l-mt.dylib     libboost_signals-mt.dylib       libboost_wserialization-mt.dylib
libboost_date_time.a            libboost_log_setup.a            libboost_math_tr1l.a            libboost_signals.a          libboost_wserialization.a
libboost_date_time.dylib        libboost_log_setup.dylib        libboost_math_tr1l.dylib        libboost_signals.dylib          libboost_wserialization.dylib
libboost_exception-mt.a         libboost_math_c99-mt.a          libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.a      libboost_system-mt.a
libboost_exception.a            libboost_math_c99-mt.dylib      libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.dylib  libboost_system-mt.dylib
libboost_filesystem-mt.a        libboost_math_c99.a         libboost_prg_exec_monitor.a     libboost_system.a
libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib        libboost_math_c99.dylib         libboost_prg_exec_monitor.dylib     libboost_system.dylib
```

Here is a pastey of [config.log](http://pastebin.com/iMg42MC6)
How do i fix this?

Comment: did you try installing it `sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev` or equivalent, depending on your os.

Comment: os is mac OS 10.9.5. i thought that is what `brew install boost` does?

Comment: So i guess it got installed somewhere where linker cant find it. Dont know about mac, though.